# Unable to get post content from custom post type loop

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, loop

For some reason I am unable to output the custom post type content using the following code. what am I missing here? It works fine for `get_the_title` yet using `get_the_content` using same parameters yields nothing.

```
<?php
            $query = new WP_Query( ['post_type' => 'testimonials', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ] );
            foreach($query->get_posts() as $testimonial):
            $meta = get_post_meta($testimonial->ID);
            foreach($meta as &$m){
                if(is_array($m)){
                    $m = $m[0];
                }
            } ?>

            <div class="content"><?=get_the_content($testimonial->ID); ?></div>
            <div class="author">- <?=get_the_title($testimonial->ID); ?> / <span class="company_name"><?=$meta['_testimonial_company_name'] ?></span></div>
            <div class="link"><a href="<?=home_url('/testimonials'); ?>" title="View All Testimonials">View More</a></div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Why are you using references `&$m`? Avoid references like the plague in PHP, also your WP_Query loop looks strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other answers mentioned, you aren't in The Loop so `get_the_*()` functions aren't going to work properly.  Since you're looping over `$query->get_posts()`  you can just use the `WP_Post` object.

Something like this will work.

```
foreach($query->get_posts() as $testimonial):
    $meta = get_post_meta($testimonial->ID);
    foreach($meta as &$m){
            if(is_array($m)){
                $m = $m[0];
            }
        }

    <div class="content"><?= do_shortcode($testimonial->post_content); ?></div>
    <div class="author">- <?=$testimonial->post_title; ?> / <span class="company_name"><?=$meta['_testimonial_company_name'] ?></span></div>
    <div class="link"><a href="<?=home_url('/testimonials'); ?>" title="View All Testimonials">View More</a></div>            

<?php endforeach;?>
```

Depending on your specific situation you may want to `wpautop()` the content as well.  E.g. `do_shortcode(wpautop($testimonial->post_content))`

If you want to setup a secondary loop, you can; however, you should NOT use `setup_postdata()` unless you are sure that you aren't working in a nested loop since that modifies the global post object.

Answer (score 0):

[`get_the_content()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content) must be used within a loop, and it requires you to set up the post's data.

You should use `setup_postdata( $post );` first, and then you can use `get_the_content()`.

However, I see a couple of issues here:

- First of all, you can use a loop, instead of foreach.
- You should never use short PHP tags. I'm surprised how your code runs at the first place.
- It's better to store your query parameters into an array for readability, and the pass it to `WP_Query();`.
- Use `the_content()` instead of `get_the_content()`, to make sure the filters are applied too.

Here is an optimized version of your code:

```
<?php
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'testimonials', 
    'posts_per_page' => 100
);
$q = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
        $q->the_post();
        $company_name = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_testimonial_company_name', true );
        ?>
        <div class="content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
        <div class="author">- <?php the_title(); ?> / <span class="company_name"><?php echo $company_name; ?></span></div>
        <div class="link"><a href="<?php echo home_url( '/testimonials' ); ?>" title="View All Testimonials">View More</a></div><?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: so would it be `foreach($query->get_posts() as $testimonial): setup_postdata( $post );` ? when i add that i get a wordpress Post content, instead of this custom post type post's content

Comment: I've updated the answer for you.

Comment: @HollerTrain that might work, but it would be non-standard and strange. Use a standard loop instead as shown in the answer, if you need the ID, there's the `$post` global variable, and `get_the_ID()`, as well as all the functions that start with `the_` which automatically pick up the post ID

Comment: Foreach is a perfectly acceptable way to iterate over a `WP_Query`.
"You should never use short PHP tags" that is incorrect, you should never use `<?` instead of `<?php` but [short echos (`<?=`) will always work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020445/what-does-mean-in-php) on modern environments.

Comment: [Not everything](https://stackoverflow.com/a/200666) is guaranteed to be run on a modern environment. Please don't encourage users toward [bad practices](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/151694). @GentlemanMax

Comment: When I say "modern" i mean PHP >= 5. Wordpress itself now recommends PHP >=7 and requires PHP 5.2.4.  Short echos `<?=` are always available and ARE considered valid and good practice by PSR-1 and by phpbestpractices.org.  What coding standard do you follow? @JackJohansson

Comment: The coding standard I use is to use `the_content();` over `do_shortcode(wpautop($testimonial->post_content));`. @GentlemanMax

Comment: So none then.  Do you have a specific problem with using `do_shortcode($testimonial->post_content)` other than it isn't what you would do? Perhaps he doesn't want the content hooks to fire in whatever context he is working on, maybe he doesn't want to require the password in this context.  There are lots of reasons that someone might not want to use `get_the_content()`?  Personally, I find `the_content()` obnoxious since it echos inside a function.